# How to get a LZW tiff with 24 bit depth from pdf file using Ghostscript

Tags: image, pdf, tiff, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript9.0, I try to generate a LZW TIFF images with **24 bit depth** from pdf file, I always get bit depth = 1 using this `GS` command:

```
gswin32.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r200 -sDEVICE=tifflzw -sOutputFile=tmp.tiff myfile.pdf
```

I searched in several manuals:

http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/8.54/Use.htm

but I didn't find anything of parameters to do that.

I add an image example proporties that I would like to produce with `gs`:

[image]

Here we can see the bit depth (profondeur de couleur) = 24 and the image is compressed with LZW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clearly stated that the format `tifflzw` you have chosen is located in the section

> The remaining TIFF drivers all
>   produce black-and-white output with
>   different compression modes

http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm

If you want a 24bit output you have to use `tiff24nc` instead and add specify the compression via the parameter `-sCompression=lzw`

```
gswin32.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r200 -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -sCompression=lzw -sOutputFile=tmp.tiff myfile.pdf
```

Comment: But we can have tifflzw compression image with 24 bit depth, see my question edit

Comment: Add the parameter -sCompression=lzw

Comment: -sCompression=lzw equals to -sDEVICE=tifflzw

Comment: Not according to http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691565 Additionally I just tested it using GhostScript 9.01 and got a fine 24bit LZW compressed PDF.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the version I am using GS 9.0